# VBA list. Help me please

Tags: excel, vba, function, finance

I have an Excel list of IPOs made in Europe from years 2000-2020 and a second list of all the loans of years 1999-2020 made in Europe. I need to find which of these IPOs from the first list received a loan from this second list of data (loan received maximum one year before the IPO). How can I do it? I wrote this code for VBA, someone can help me to adjust it please? Is there a simpler way to do it?

[image]

code:

```
Sub

i = 2

Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""

j = 2
Cells(i, 5).Value = 0

Do Until Cells(j, 3).Value = "" Or Cells(i, 5).Value = 1

If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value Then

    If Cells(i, 1).Value > Cells(j, 3).Value And Cells(i, 1).Value < Cells(j, 3).Value And Cells(i, 1).Value > Cells(j, 3).Value - 365 Then
            Cells(i, 5).Value = 1
    
    End If
    
    j = 1 + i
    
    Loop
    
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I can achieve your result w/o VBA using this formula

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B7,$F$4:$G$7,1,FALSE)),0,IF(AND((C7-(VLOOKUP(B7,$F$4:$G$7,2,FALSE))<365),(C7-(VLOOKUP(B7,$F$4:$G$7,2,FALSE))>0)),1,0))
```

[image]

In case you want to maintain the sequence of your column, then you have to use index-match function to replace Vlookup

Comment: thank you Kin Siang. I tried to use it, but if I insert a date that is also 365 days after the IPO date, it gives me 1. Do you know how can I fix it? I need the "1" only when the Date loan is before (max 365) the IPO date and not also after. For example, if you insert in G4 a date 1-Mar-21, you will have 1 (and not 0) as result even if it is after the IPO date.

Comment: Sound simple. You can check the above formula, i just add another condition to check the day range is between -365 and 365, then return 1., you can compare Company a & e, is it what you want?

Comment: Regarding the date, what I mean is that the function should give 1 only if: 1)"Date loan" is before "IPO date" AND 2)"Date loan" is max 365days before "IPO date" (so any "Date loan" after "IPO date" should give 0). In this case, Company e should return 0 because it is after IPO date. In the case of Company a, this should correctly give 1 because 1/3/19 is 306days (less than 365 days) before IPO date.

Comment: You can check the change above, so i set the day range is more than 0, and less than 365, and return the result exactly as you wish, is it what you want?